# Install Netbeans in WIndows 10

Tags: java, build, project, netbeans-8

I am using windows 10 and I downloaded JDK 7u80 and downloaded NetBeans 8.2.
I install JDK separately.

when I am going to install NetBeans it shows a message that JDK is not install in the computer.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I found the Solution for this.

Here need to set the environmental path variable and home variable.

In the control panel -> system -> advances system settings -> environmental variables ->path -> add a new path of JDK bin folder in C ->program files -> java -> JDK -> bin

To set the Home variable in the environment variable add a new environmental variable as JAVA_HOME and add the path of C ->program files -> java -> JDK